# Stock take information

Tags: inventory

Is it possible to export a report showing stock levels of all simple products at a date in the past? Or export a report showing current stock?

Answer (score 2):

You could use dataflow for the current stock levels:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEBOQnrY2K4

The stock levels on a given date are not stored and are extremely hard to reproduce later. It should be possible to calculate them based on sales, creditmemo and cancellations of (unpaid) orders.

Comment: But this recalulation  expects to have no qty updates from outside. If you updated the qty in the past, there is no way to reproduce the stock in any time in the past before this,.